# Laravel Session - can't get session values

Tags: laravel, session

I use the '`database`' option for sessions, so the sessions are stored in the sessions table.
I can't get any value using the session helper, or by using the `$request` instance, it outputs nothing.
For example in the Indexcontroller for the main page:

```
echo "id is : " . session('id');
echo "id is : " . ($request->session()->get('id'));
```

The current session is being stored in the sessions table though.

If I import the Session facade and printing it, it seems pretty empty?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

echo '<pre>';
        print_r(Session::all());
        echo '<pre/>';
```

result:

```
 Array
    ( [_token] => qvecCorEZebmfToVYjjegzOML382gS67KEqYXuySj
        [link] => http://mydomain.loc
        [_previous] => Array
            ( [url] => http://mydomain.loc) 
        [_flash] => Array
            ([old] => Array ()
                [new] => Array ())
```

If I try to print php session:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I get `Undefined variable: _SESSION`.

If I import the \App\Session model , I can get session table records.
There is a cookie called '`laravel_session`' that stores the id,which I can retrieve with the facade:  `Session::getId();` I could match that to the record from the database. But that would be some kind of workaround?

Comment: You haven't shown any code that puts anything in the session, which explains there not being anything there? :-)

Comment: But it's handled automatically, if I delete the session record in db and reload the page, I get a new session, it is filled automatically? Do you mean that the session needs to be populated manually somewhere?

Comment: HTTP sessions are used to store data between requests.  If you want to use them, the first step is to store some data. Then, on a different page, you can read that data back.  I guess you know this already though, otherwise what are you trying to use sessions for?  You have configured Laravel to use sessions, so it is setting things up, ready for you to use.  The DB record is where any data you store will be saved.  Have a read of [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session), they are pretty good.

Comment: @Galivan something like `session()->put('key', 'value')`

Comment: the 'id' you are referring to with `Session::getId()` is the id of the session to identify it, that 'id' is not part of the session data for that session though

Comment: The session table is generated with an artisan command...they have the columns: Id , user_id, ip_address , user_agent, last_activity. I have just assumed that these values are retrieved and stored automatically within some of the middlewares like "StartSession" in Kernel.php. How does the session data end up in the table? I'm not doing anything.

Comment: yes sessions can be created but it doesn't mean there will automatically be data in the payload ... and yes there is a session store that uses what ever driver you have configured that the `StartSession` middleware will interact with to make sure there is a session for the request

Comment: But if I choose to store sessions in "array" instead of database, will that be the normal php session storage...or do I still need to add the vaules with ->put().

Comment: Laravel does not use PHP's session system ...and array would mean it is being held only in an array, which means at the end of the request it is gone ... to add things to the session you have to use what ever the docs tell you to use

Comment: Allright. so laravel first saves values into db, then I go and retrieve the same values from the db and put them in session.It seems that I could get those values before they are saved to db and don't need to fetch them. I have not found any part of the docs that shows this workflow. But thanks for informing!

Comment: What isn't clear to me still is , if I would save the session data manually, I must get the values from the db, so I must get the current session id - and the only way to get it is to retrieve it from the laravel_session cookie.

Comment: you don't interact with the database directly you interact with the session store, `$request->session()->put('something', 'something');` ... then later on another request `$request->session()->get('something');`

Answer (score 1):

#### You can try

```
$request->session->put('key','value);
$request->session()->save();

$request->session()->get('key');
```

###### This makes the session persistent